# HTML+CSS+D3 to pdf with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, pdf, d3.js

How can make a pdf with jQuery, that can show tables and D3 same as it is in my browser?

Im in loss, as of where to start?
Is there a plugin what could handle this?

So far tryd with jsPDF but it does not take CSS along. It would be awesome if the data and graph CSS would stay the same, positions the same. Like take a picture of all of it and put in PDF file. Text should be able to be copy-d in pdf.

OR??? convert somehow graph to image? and html2cancas(jspdf) but still lost CSS everywhere ( i have external CSS files)

Because i haven't tryd anything like this before, I would like to know where to start and how (success a plugin or there is command jsPDF that i forgot?)

PS! fiddle is something i found and edited http://jsfiddle.net/jYLXN/328/

HTML

```
<script src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>


 <table border="1" id="table" class="table table-bordered" style="width: 400px ">
                        <thead class="thead-inverse">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Month</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1.Month average</td>
                            <td>555</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>.....</td>
                            <td>.....</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>12.Month average</td>
                            <td>666</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Year average</td>
                            <td>585</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input type="button" value="Save pdf"
                               onclick="genPDF();">
```

JS

```
 var svg = d3.select("svg"),
            margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
            width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
            y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
            z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var line = d3.line()
            .curve(d3.curveBasis)
            .x(function (d) {
                return x(d.date);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return y(d.temperature);
            });


    d3.tsv("{{url_for('static', filename='_custom/data.tsv', _external=True)}}", type, function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function (id) {
            return {
                id: id,
                values: data.map(function (d) {
                    return {date: d.date, temperature: d[id]};
                })
            };
        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.date;
        }));

        y.domain([
            d3.min(cities, function (c) {
                return d3.min(c.values, function (d) {
                    return d.temperature;
                });
            }),
            d3.max(cities, function (c) {
                return d3.max(c.values, function (d) {
                    return d.temperature;
                });
            })
        ]);

        z.domain(cities.map(function (c) {
            return c.id;
        }));

        g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
                .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", "0.71em")
                .attr("fill", "#000")
                .text("Temperature, ºF");

        var city = g.selectAll(".city")
                .data(cities)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "city");

        city.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", function (d) {
                    return line(d.values);
                })
                .style("stroke", function (d) {
                    return z(d.id);
                });

        city.append("text")
                .datum(function (d) {
                    return {id: d.id, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]};
                })
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
                })
                .attr("x", 3)
                .attr("dy", "0.35em")
                .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.id;
                });
    });

    function type(d, _, columns) {
        d.date = parseTime(d.date);
        for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
        return d;
    }

function genPDF() {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
            pdf.text(20,20, 'Workstation: '+wsname+ ' statistics');
            source = $('#tablef')[0];

            specialElementHandlers = {
                '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true
                }
            };
            margins = {
                top: 80,
                bottom: 60,
                left: 40,
                width: 522
            };
            pdf.fromHTML(
                    source,
                    margins.left,
                    margins.top, {
                        'width': margins.width,
                        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                    },

                    function (dispose) {

                        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
                    }, margins);
        }
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-image: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/white-polygons-background_23-2147512309.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1000px 500px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: The most important thing in a question is called "question".

Comment: Why is this tagged `d3.js` when it seems to be a question about highcharts?  Have you seen the highcharts [exporting capabilities](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview)?

Comment: Im sorry as it says this was another person fiddle, that i edited. Im using D3, but the general idea, still the same. And Gerardo, the question is - How can make a pdf, with jQuery, that can show tables and D3 same as it is in my browser

Comment: That being the case, I suggest you edit your question and make that point clearer.

Comment: That being the question ... I suggest you show a page or fiddle ... with JQuery and Tables and d3 that you want printed.